# "KeyError: 'Records'" in AWS S3 - Lambda trigger

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have the following lambda function code for simply printing out the Author and metadata of an uploaded event of an S3 bucket:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import urllib
import boto3

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    # bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']

    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record[0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record[0]['s3']['object']['key']
        response = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

        logger.info('Response: {}'.format(response))

        print("Author : " + response['Metadata']['author'])
        print("Description : " + response['Metadata']['description'])
```

However, I am getting the following error while testing:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      17,
      "lambda_handler",
      "for record in event['Records']:"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "errorMessage": "'Records'"
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong while accessing the bucket name and key name of the S3 object?  If not, then what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What type of S3 event trigger are you using?

Comment: @franklinsijo `Event type: ObjectCreated`

Comment: And is this a test event or actual event?. Can you print the `event` and check whether it contains `Records`?

Comment: If this is test, it is possible that you have configured the default test event which does not contain `Records` key.

Comment: @franklinsijo Yeah. That might be it. Thanks.  However, the CloudWatch logs shows me this error: `'key1': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 10, in lambda_handler
print("value1 = " + event['key1'])
KeyError: 'key1'`

Comment: Is this solved with configuring the test event?

Comment: @Dawny33 is it solved? I have same issue.

Comment: I have the same exact issue but I don't follow the explanation below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

bit late to the party. But here is my first post!

**EXPLANATION:**

When you test in lambda panel -> def lambda_handler(event, context) <- event is injected directly.

However in AWS API its neccessary to **add Mapping Template** or otherwise -> event <- is empty, thus resulting in quizzing:

> "errorType": "KeyError", "errorMessage": "'Records'"

this is null pointer. Records doesnt exist, since -> event <- doesnt exist.

**SOLUTION:**

You need to configure **Integration Request** inside AWS API. 
Click on **Body Mapping Templates**.
Then **add Mapping Template**
Set content type to **application/json**
Then edit generated mapping template:

```html
{
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "params": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "query": {
    #foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$queryParam": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  }  
}
```

And **edit Lambda function**:

replace:

> for record in event['Records']:

with:

> for record in event['query']['Records']

don't know whether stack will ping you with this answer - so i call you @Dawny33 @KevinOelen @franklinsijo

As for explanation i figured it on my own. However "mapping template" comes from https://medium.com/simple-thoughts-amplified/passing-variables-from-aws-api-gateway-to-lambda-3c5d8602081b

Comment: what if i am trying to execute lambda without API call then how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue yesterday and the problem is when you run a test there isn't actually any event (def lambda_handler(event, context)) for lambda to process. The event document is normally generated when an actual event occurs which is a json doc, your python code parses this document and then retrieves the keys. So the solution is for you to create an actual event by dropping a file in s3 so long as you have created event notification then this would get picked up

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue , **what we need to do here is very simple. Region of the lambda and region while creating the bucket/ trigger should be same.** If it is same simply upload files to S3 bucket will be reflected to DynamoDB Directly.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issues and what worked for me ... is that stop running the test on lambda function and just go to your s3 bucket and upload your json file and all will be okay . trust me i was also having same headaches as you right now ..

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31290255)