# “KeyError: 'Records'” in AWS S3 - Lambda trigger

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm getting an error after using this code, I used Postman to find the error.

```
import json
from botocore.vendored import requests

URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?text="

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    body = event["body"]
    url = URL + body + "&chat_id=<chat-id>"
    requests.get(url)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200
    }
```

and here is the error I'm getting but I'm not quite sure how to fix it:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "'body'",
    "errorType": "KeyError",
    "stackTrace": [
        [
            "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
            7,
            "lambda_handler",
            "body = event[\"body\"]"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to configure Integration Request inside AWS API. Click on
>   Body Mapping Templates. Then add Mapping Template Set content type to
>   application/json Then edit generated mapping template:

Reference:

["KeyError: 'Records'" in AWS S3 - Lambda trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795438/keyerror-records-in-aws-s3-lambda-trigger)